# How do you fix the following error? I am trying to Data Table Import Wizard to load a csv file into Workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, import, encoding, mysql-workbench

I am trying to upload a .csv file into Workbench using the Table Data Import Wizard.

I receive the following error whenever attempting to load it:

Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1253: ordinal not in range(128)

I have tried previous solutions that suggested I encode the .csv file as a MS-DOS csv and as a UTF-8 csv. Neither have worked for me.

Attempting to change the data in the file would not be feasible since its made up of thousands of cells, so it would quite impractical. Is there anything that can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

What was after the `C3`?  What should have been there?

`C3`, when interpreted as "latin1" is `Ã` -- an unlikely character.

More likely is a 2-byte UTF-8 code that starts with C3.  This includes the accented letters of Western European languages.  Example `é`, hex `C3A9`.

You tried "UTF-8 csv" -- Please provide the specifics of how you tried it.  What settings in the Wizard, etc.

Probably you should state that the data is "UTF-8" or `utf8mb4`, depending on whether you are referring to outside or inside MySQL.

Meanwhile, if you are loading the data into an existing "table", let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It should probably not say "ascii" anywhere; instead, it should probably say "utf8mb4".